# Updating State In React With React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been having a difficult time updating state inside of my React application lately using the `useState` hook.

If I define my state in a provider as -

```
const [session, setSession] = useState({});
const [sessionId, setSessionId] = useState(0);
```

And then try to set it using the `setSession`

```
setSession(response.data);
```

It always comes back as the default value. This all happens inside of the provider component - i.e. I'm trying to access the information within other functions in that same provider.

However, if I store that data in localStorage, for example, I have no issues accessing it whatsoever.

```
localStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

I've verified that the information coming from the server is an object, and that the correct data. There's no errors or promises, just the object containing the response. If I put the snippet the `setSession(response.data)` and `localStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify(response.data))` next to each other, the `setSession` leaves the `session` value as `{}` whereas setting the local storage works perfectly. Both are using the same API response, same data

```js
// This is the method on my component that I'm trying to use to update the state
const updateStateAfterSessionInitialization = async data => {
    setSession(data)
    localStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify(data));
    setSessionId(data.id);

    // both of these log a value of `{}` and `0` despite the values being set above
    console.log(session)
    console.log(sessionId)
    closeStartSessionModal();

    // If I redirect my application like this, it works fine. The ID is the correct value being returned by the server
    window.location = "/#/reading-sessions/" + data.id;
}

// All of this code below is wrapped in a function. None of this code is being executed at the top level
let response = await axios({
    method: method,
    data:data,
    url: url,
    headers: headers
});

await updateStateAfterSessionInitialization(response.data);
```

Literally all of the data is working perfectly fine. The server responds with the correct data, the correct data is stored the session in local storage. If I redirect using the ID from the object from the server, it works fine. But if I try to update the state of the component and access the state properly, it just just doesn't work, and as a result I'm having to try to find ways of working around setting the state.

Is there something that I'm misunderstanding here?

The code that I'm working with is here - https://github.com/aaronsnig501/decyphr-ui/commit/ef04d27c4da88cd909ce38f53bbc1babcc3908cb#diff-25d902c24283ab8cfbac54dfa101ad31

Thanks

Comment: What is your `response.data`? Where do you get that?

Comment: Could you share the surrounding code for `setSession(response.data);`?

Comment: `response.data` is undefined. It seems that you're using axios to make some API request. Perhaps you're not using async/await, a `.then()` when making the request, the URL could be wrong (typo) or the API server is down. As you can see lot's of possibilities, it would be good to narrow it down if you add a more complete snippet.

Comment: I've updated this with my code and explanation. Thanks

Comment: I don’t think we see the whole picture from posted code. More code or a codesandbox is appreciated.

Comment: I can't give a full example in the codesandbox right now. I want to call the API when a user clicks on the `Start Session` button. When the button is pressed, it calls the API successfully, but doesn't update the state of the component. The `setSession` function ins't performing the task that it should. The data is available from the API, but the state is not updating with this information. I can do literally anything else with the data, but update the state

Answer (score 3):

The misunderstanding you have here is an assumption that state updates will reflect immediately which is incorrect

State update is async and will only refect in the next render cycle. If you try to update state and log it in the next line, you wouldn't see and updated state

```
// This is the method on my component that I'm trying to use to update the state
const updateStateAfterSessionInitialization = async data => {
    setSession(data)
    localStorage.setItem("session", JSON.stringify(data));
    setSessionId(data.id);

    // both of these log a value of `{}` and `0` despite the values being set above
    console.log(session) // This is expected to log previous value
    console.log(sessionId) // This is expected to log previous value
    closeStartSessionModal();

    window.location = "/#/reading-sessions/" + data.id;
}
```

Now localStorage is synchronous and hence its update is reflected immediately

If you wish to see if the update to state was done correctly you could write a useEffect that depends on it

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('State session/sessionId updated');
}, [session, sessionId])
```

Now depending on what you are trying to achieve you would need to modify your code in line with the above statement that state update calls are asynchronous.

Also setSession doesn't return a promise so you can't just use async await with it. You need to make use of `useEffect` to take an action on state update

Comment: Ah, okay. I think the thing that I misunderstood was that react would re-render on state change. This is the case for `setState`, no? This provider was originally class-based and as such, used this approach and I didn't have any problems. I just updated it as all the rest of my providers were function based. Maybe it would be best if I revert to a class-based provider and make use of the `setState`. This explanation has been super helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually there isn't much of behavioural difference between class and functional component internally. The cycle is still the same. A few APIs have changed. and yes on state update a re-render is triggered but the function scope values are not changed

Answer (score 0):

For Example:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
      console.log(result.data);
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(res => (
        <li>{res.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Check your type of `response.data` and defined the types 
array - []
objects - {}
string - ""
number - 0 in `useState`

Comment: I've verified that it is an object. I've viewed the response from the server and in local storage

Answer (score 0):

setState is async, so new value will apply on the next rerender not in the next line.